# When you encounter an error, stackexchange should not respond with the error page when you reload

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-deferred, 500-server-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refreshing error pages lead to error pages even after the error is fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed)

As an example, I encountered an error and was directed to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/10796092/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-first-name-last-name-email-password

I kept reloading the page, thinking it would show me the content I requested when it recovered from whatever caused the error.

However, it took me quite a while to realize I was no longer making requests to the address I thought I was at.

When I reload the page that caused the error, it should show me the page I originally requested, if there is no longer a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that would actually be kinda nice.