# Oops! Something bad happened with recently active question

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

I was just scrolling in [recently active section](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) on meta and I got curious about a question [with about 50 upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent), so decided to view it and I got this error page

> [image]

What has happened here??

It shows it has been modified 40 min ago, which means it was active then..

Was the question deleted?

Or just a crash??

Comment: If you keep going to the error page, you will keep getting the error page ;)

Comment: @Oded Well, it seems to be solved now, QUICK FIX :P

Comment: it seems to be working now

Comment: I saw a similar blip earlier browsing to a deleted answer from a user profile.

Comment: @Oded, you were right, refreshing(already opened page with error as in image) doesn't solves the problem, opening in new link does, But, I must say, you were pretty fast to solve it and tag it as norepro..  :P

Comment: Heh - it appeared to be transient.

Comment: It's possible it was being edited when you were looking at it, the time frames seem to match

Comment: @Yve Highly possible...

Comment: @CRUSADER I noticed it was edited, as in some round about way it was linked to one of the posts my own posts, and I had just edited a few, so was noticing the queue change yada yada..so when you linked that question in your question I was not surprised..  if any of that makes sense

Comment: OMG I am not kidding, I just tried to upvote your question and got the red error message!!! hahahahahahahhaha I think the Meta site has  a consciousness

Comment: @Yve Hmm... Highly possible it was in edit queue, but, I never saw such page before on SO, moreover most of times refreshing the page solves the problem, but that was not case here, so I reported...

Comment: @CRUSADER yep, that's why I gave you the upvote ;)

Comment: @Yve Thanks for your support. Appreciated.

Comment: @CRUSADER no worries and people do it for me :))

Comment: @Oded, as for *"If you keep going to the error page..."*, okay, [fix that already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed)! ;-)