# Eeek! Stack Exchange devs have devoured the lolcat

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, 500-server-error

Once upon a time, Stack Overflow used to have cool [error page](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/) with a lolcat:

> [image]

But... it's hard to say it... the cat is no more and was replaced with no else than [Jarrod Dixon](https://stackexchange.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) who is also shamelessly using The [V-Tech Talking Whiz Kid Mouse PRO Deluxe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53227/152859)!

> [image]

Please bring the cat back! :)

Oh, and the funny thing is the image is still located in "error-cats": `http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/457516628.jpg`

Edit: just noticed it's **rotating**! Also seen: Marc, unknown devs (maybe even Oded?!), <strike>**but no cats**</strike>.

OK, finally found [the poor cat](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/681791902.jpg) but it's just one of so many!

Comment: nice free-hand-circle, but I still don't see any difference in the two pictures

Comment: find 1 difference in the pic

Comment: Railing in background is different. Cup moved.

Comment: @Sklivvz come on, at least some explanation why it was changed? :(

Comment: While bringing back lolcat, it would be nice if the primary server could be brought back too :P

Comment: @TravisJ nah, it got bugs so the cat will just eat them.

Comment: @Sklivvz So, Jarrod is supposed to eat the cats?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - If Jarrod ate the cats then who is supposed to eat the bugs?!

Comment: @Sklivvz Since this is by design, how about we use the cat on  [Pets.SE](http://pets.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: The red outline was incredibly helpful, Thank you from the bottom of my heart, no, seriously ><.

Comment: @Ricardo Don't tell me you're badmouthing Meta's [freehand red circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/161198) ...

Comment: If you don't think that's one cool cat, you've never met Jarrod.

Comment: I'm disappointed nobody's got a full image list yet.  That code was fun to write.

Comment: @KevinMontrose: So am I

Comment: @KevinMontrose challenge accepted!

Comment: @Bart You're really seeing a circle there, aren't you. Well, I'm glad it was helpful to you too lol.

Comment: I saw the cat earlier, but in strange circumstances. It appeared while the page was loading, but not once the load was complete, a picture of some human appeared. This happened several times. I could only see the cat whilst a page was loading (not always while a page was loading) but never after the load was complete.

Comment: Just checked. Still doing the same for me. Cat appears, then disappears when page loads. Same cat, different human/humanoid.

Comment: @Bill yep they made it client side.

Comment: On a serious note, @Kevin: now that the error image is client side, can't you also do [some client side `history.pushState` trickery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed/148632#148632) to get a reloadable (homepage) URL into the browser's location bar?

Comment: How's that list going, @ShaWizDowArd? (I noticed even [the non-minimized version](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/error-cats.js) is, er, minimized. No luck there!)

Comment: @Arjan found 34 so far as [mentioned here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203635/152859), feel free to [help the cause](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XAYnF/2/) and add any new pictures you discover!

Comment: @Manishearth I think you meant to ping Arjan, not Kevin?

Comment: @KevinMontrose I got the full image list (see below). You should have your jQuery license revoked for that code.

Comment: @Manishearth also, think he got a typo... should it be `parseInt("life", 36)`? ;-)

Comment: You might have missed this related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page

Comment: @Jake umm... I posted answer there how exactly could I miss it??

Comment: Heh, I should pay more attention to who I'm commenting at.  :D  On the plus side, now there's a reference to the related question on this one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The cat is there, don't you worry. The images are rotated between our dev staff *and* that cat is still one of the options for the rotation.

Comment: So you hire cats now? Just don't let him eat all the bugs! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Of course we hire cats...

Comment: Who but Mr Mittens could be the community manager for pets.se?

Comment: @Kasra one last question... who is the unicorn? :P

Answer (score 19):

There is also an blue-eyed unicorn:

[image: Horse error]

Edit: as requested by Sha Wiz Dow Ard, here is [the proof](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/365705759.jpg).

Comment: Proof please, what is the picture real URL? Reloaded tons of times and never seeen it.

Comment: I've seen it. Isn't that proof enough?

Comment: The computer and the table are the same, is it not enough for you? :) In fact, it's only displayed to _special_ users. (just kidding, I updated my answer)

Comment: Cool, it was just hard to believe!

Comment: Just saw that one as well.  sweet.

Comment: Holy Sh!@$#, unicorns really DO exist in the web industry!!! :O

Answer (score 15):

[Found all of them (there are 34, no more)](http://pastebin.com/CAvpM6Vc)

### Method:

I took the code over [here](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/js/error-cats.js?v=b48b82c1c69a) and started building upon it.

Firstly, I noticed that the final function was of this form:

```
function(t, o, x, z, p)
        {
            var s,
                y,
                w;
            var q = (Math.random() * 100) ^ 0;
            var u = q < 50 ? 0 : q < 75 ? 1 : q < 88 ? 2 : 3;
            s = l(o, x, z, p)[u];
            y = (Math.random() * s.b) ^ 0;
            var r = y;
            while (y >= 0)
            {
                w = s.a();
                if (c(231, [null, w]))
                {
                    y = y - 1
                }
            }
            var v = document.getElementById("error-cat");
            v.src = t + w + ".jpg";
            v.className = ""
        };
```

It gets called as `StackExchange.error.init('https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/', 9, 9, 15, 1);`.

I knew that if I could remove the randomness from the code and replace it with iterations through all the possible values of the discretized random numbers, I'd be done.

Looking at `var u = q < 50 ? 0 : q < 75 ? 1 : q < 88 ? 2 : 3;`, `u` takes only 4 values, from 0 to 3.

Similarly, `y` takes only `s.b` values. `s.b` is `l(o, x, z, p)[u].b`. `l` is defined as

```
  l = function(r, q, o, p)
        {
            return [{
                        a: h(parseInt("thatisnot", 36)), b: r
                    }, {
                        a: h(parseInt("deadwhich", 36)), b: q
                    }, {
                        a: h(parseInt("caneternal", 36)), b: o
                    }, {
                        a: h(parseInt("lie", 36)), b: p
                    }]
        }
```

The `b` value is copied from the parameters of `l`, which is copied from the parameters of `init`. So I can just replace this code with

```
l = function()
{
    return [{
                a: h(parseInt("thatisnot", 36)), b: 9
            }, {
                a: h(parseInt("deadwhich", 36)), b: 9
            }, {
                a: h(parseInt("caneternal", 36)), b: 15
            }, {
                a: h(parseInt("lie", 36)), b: 1
            }]
},
```

and then I can replace `y = (Math.random() * s.b) ^ 0;` with a for loop from 0 to `s.b`, where `s=s = l()[u];`.

Similarly, the assignment for `u` can be replaced by a for loop from 0 to 3.

One would expect this to work, but the devs are pretty sneaky and managed to create exotic errors:

```
TypeError: Property 'puundefinedh' of object [object Array] is not a function
```

This meant that for some crazy reason, someone was trying to call `Array.push()`, except they were constructing the string `"push"` character by character and then using `a["push"]` to push to the array (if `a` was the array). Such code demands immediate revocation of jQuery licenses in usual circumstances, no doubt.

Anyway, I found likely candidates for this in the code in three places:

```
s[k[3] + ("" + m)[0] + ("" + !!0)[3] + k[0]](x)
...
return s[k[3] + ("" + {})[1] + k[3]]()
...
 t(v()[("" + !!0)[3] + ("" + m)[0] + ("" + {})[2] + ("" + !!0)[3] + ("" + {})[6] + ("" + !0)[1] + ("" + m)[5] + ("" + m)[1] + (typeof(""))[5]](v(), v()));
```

The first one is an obfuscation of `"push"`, the second of `"pop"`, the third of `"substring"`. I replaced these with their literal counterparts, and the code worked.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/RWzschvH) is the final code. Run it in the terminal on the error page, along with `StackExchange.error.init()`, and the 2D array of links  should be printed to the console.

A day may come when I understand the full obfuscation, but it is not this day. This day we oscillate!

Comment: `s/33/34/`? (My text editor says 34 lines in that code block.)

Comment: ...don't bother; see [How can I see all the images of the error page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/how-can-i-see-all-the-images-of-the-error-page/203635#203635) and Kevin's comments. (Though I'm curious how you got the list.)

Comment: @Arjan Posting the details now. Was pretty simple, actually.

Comment: @Arjan updated with method (and collapsed the list), see above

Comment: I found all 34 by brute force, you took the elegant route - nice!

Comment: Now, what if `9, 9, 15, 1` are other values...? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan I don't think anything happens. Decreasing them will give you less images, increasing them doesn't seem to create more images (just 404s) but I'll have to check.

Comment: (Pssst, Kevin already said there are 34 images, so I'm sure it won't change. Soon.)

Comment: @Manishearth seems like `159632722.jpg` & `420906910.jpg` & `456788979.jpg` are duplicates that makes your list shorter by 3

Comment: @Manishearth oh actually one more `819884963.jpg`

Comment: You are missing my picture!

Comment: @Sklivvz Hmm, is it in the code? Or do we need to do some additional tweaking to get to it?

Comment: @Sklivvz just saw your request, [added it here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/203635/152859) - you can now add yourself to the lolcats! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Argh, I was just trolling Manish, you are taking me too seriously :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I can never reject a good challenge, sorry! :D

Answer (score 5):

It appears there are a set of images which are loaded, with a variety of people.  I can't be sure if sometimes a cat will be shown... perhaps we just need a higher percentage of cats in the mix?

Comment: Yeah, +1 for noticing it's rotating, lol! :)