# Sub-optimal 500 error redirection

Tags: bug, user-experience

I recently followed a link from google to this question: [How can I set custom signatures across a domain Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372219/how-can-i-set-custom-signatures-across-a-domain-gmail-api) and got presented a 500 error page. That's OK, 500's happen sometimes, but naturally I tried to refresh the page a few times to see if the error would go away - it didn't. That's when I looked at the url and saw I had been redirected to:

> https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/40372219/how-can-i-set-custom-signatures-across-a-domain-gmail-api

More specifically, `/error?aspxerrorpath=` had been inserted at the root of the path - so subsequent requests would *always* fail. After I manually removed this from the path, the page loaded fine.

A better behavior would be to render the 500 page at the same path as the request so that a refresh would clear up the issue.

A comment mentioned that this has been asked before. In [the previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed), this issue was dismissed as it wasn't built into MVC4, but I argue it could be done with a custom middleware as long as the response hasn't been started yet.

Aspnet provides an example [error handling middleware implementation here](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/ExceptionHandler/ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.cs).

Comment: 500's happen sometimes but as we speak we have a lot of those: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363730/systematic-this-is-our-fault-on-some-links

Comment: I was just searching for this too, found an older thread from 2012: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147232/refreshing-error-pages-lead-to-error-pages-even-after-the-error-is-fixed

Comment: Most likely Stack Exchange will not work on asp.net core. However the classic MVC framework offers the `HandleErrorAttribute`.

Comment: Yes, at least put a link on the error page so I don't have to copy the URL from the error URL and paste.

Comment: On-going issue, devs are working on it. They'll reply once this is fixed likely, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363730/systematic-this-is-our-fault-on-some-links) (issue is problematic beyond aspxerrorpath sub-optimally persisting).